# An exact fraction of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-geometry, eigenvalues, data-analysis

Let $A$ be a $n \times m$ real matrix with $n<<m$ and of rank $r<n$. It is known that $A$ has exactly two distinct non-zero singular values: $\sigma_{\max}$ and $\sigma_{2}$, and also that $\sigma_{\max}$ is simple.

> **Question**: Under what conditions on $A$ and $p$ is it possible to select a subset
>   of $p$ columns, forming a $n \times p$ submatrix $B$ so that $p|m$ and
>   that the singular values of $B$ are precisely those of $A$, divided by
>   $\sqrt{\frac{m}{p}}$?

What if $A$ has only $\{0,1\}$ entries?

This can be viewed, I think, as a variation on the Column Subset Selection Problem (CSSP) on which a lot of work has been done lately (for example: [here](http://web.stanford.edu/group/mmds/slides2008/tropp.pdf)).

Comment: What's the relation of $M$ and $A$?

Comment: @AllenKnutson $M$ is $A$. Fixing now, Thanks.